# Converting quadratic form into Bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a big problem with what appears to be a basic question concerning quadratic and bilinear forms.

Q: Let $B$ be a symmetric bilinear form with associated quadratic form $Q(x, y, z) = 4xy − 2xz − 4yz − y^2$

Write down the matrix of the bilinear form $B$ with respect to the usual basis. I have the answer here but no idea how it was obtained.

This is my first time asking a question so sorry if the format is incorrect.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add all relevant details, including the answer, and what you have tried and why you think it is wrong. Looking at the answer won't usually help you *get* the answer.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  \boldsymbol{x}^T \mathbb{B}\, \boldsymbol{x} &= -y^2-4yz-2zx+4xy \\[5pt]
  \mathbb{B} &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 2 & -1 \\
    2 & -1 & -2 \\
    -1 & -2 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you tell me how you obtained the matrix for B?

Comment: In general,$$\begin{pmatrix}
  x & y & z \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  a & h & g \\
  h & b & f \\
  g & f & c
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\
  y \\
  z
\end{pmatrix}=ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2fyz+2gzx+2hxy$$
and do it backward.  Are you OK in finding the eigenvectors or even the orthogonal bases?

Comment: Once I knew the matrix B finding the eigenvectors and orthonormal bases were no problem. I just had initial problems finding B. But this helped a lot, thanks for your answer!